# Doctrine2 not respecting group by with mixed object/aggregate selection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Given existing data and the grouping of tasks and dates, I expect the following DQL to produce 1,448 results:

```php
<?php
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery(
        <<<DQL
SELECT t, SUM(a.hours) hours, a.date
JOIN AppBundle\Entity\Task t
JOIN AppBundle\Entity\Actual a WITH a.Task=t
GROUP BY t, a.date
ORDER BY t.taskCode, a.date
DQL
    );

$sql = $query->getSQL();
$results = $query->getResult();
```

The generated SQL does return the result set expected.  However, $results contains only one record per Task entity (21).  Within each of those, only the last date and the corresponding sum of hours is present.

If I change the SELECT from "t" to "t.TaskId," it returns all 1,448 records, but then I am faced with the unhappy task of reconstructing all of the Task entities after the fact.

Am I missing something obvious about the GROUP BY clause or how to fetch the results in a useful way?